NotSupportedException: The member IssueDate of type System.DateOnly cannot be used as a parameter value
I have the following code which inserts data into the SQL server database. The database table DataEntries column IssueDate is of data type Date. There is a problem with the IssueDate = DateOnly.MinValue. When I run the following code.
    DataEntry l_DataEntries = new()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        IssueDate = DateOnly.MinValue
    };
    var DataEntriesQ = @"
    INSERT [dbo].[DataEntries](
        [CreatedAt],
        [IssueDate]
    ) VALUES (
        @CreatedAt,
        @IssueDate
    ); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
    int dataEntryId = dbContext.QueryAsync<int>(DataEntriesQ, l_DataEntries).Result.SingleOrDefault();

I get the following exception

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The member
IssueDate of type System.DateOnly cannot be used as a
parameter value)'
Inner Exception: NotSupportedException: The member
IssueDate of type System.DateOnly cannot be used as a
parameter value

Here's the model for DataEntry.
public class DataEntry
{
    ...
    public DateOnly? IssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
}


Well this discussion seems to indicate that (at least at some point) Dapper did not have support for DateOnly and TimeOnly types. I suggest that you pass your parameter as a DateTime type.

You're setting yourself up for a fall with this. C#'s DateTime min value(year 0001) is far earlier in history than SQLS DATE can support (year1753). Use nullable types to represent no date, not min values. Use DATETIME2 in SQLS. Use DateTimes instead of DateOnly; DateOnly came along decades after SQLS date was invented, and they aren't necessarily mapped with each other by existing libraries. Also.. Don't use Async overloads and then call .Result (that is not making anything asynchronous at all), either await the Async properly or use the synchronous methods

Which Dapper version is used? The latest version should support DateOnly

Ran into this while using the latest version of Dapper as of this writing. Although some have made custom handlers, such as can be found here: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/1715 , I found that the Quickest/Easiest solution for me was to just have my Dates set as DateTime types in my C# model, but have the table column types in SQL Server be just Date types. This truncates the time off as it is stored in the database, and proved a nice solution for now (until support for DateOnly gets better).

DateOnly is not supported natively, but it's not a problem since you can register a type handler for it.
Just call a static method AddTypeHandler during application initialization:
Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DateOnlyTypeHandler());

Sample DateOnlyTypeHandler looks like that:
public class DateOnlyTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateOnly>
{
    public override DateOnly Parse(object value)
    {
        return value is DateOnly dateOnly
            ? dateOnly
            : DateOnly.FromDateTime((DateTime)value);
    }

    public override void SetValue([DisallowNull] IDbDataParameter parameter, DateOnly value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue);
        parameter.DbType = DbType.Date;
    }
}

adjust it to the requirements of your database connector.
